# I have a merchant that only takes bitcoins can I just put the correct amount in the wallet and then pay them?

Tags: transactions

I want to pay a merchant who only takes bitcoin payments. Do I create a wallet and only put in the amount of the price and pay with it? If so then what do I do after I send it to the merchant?

Answer (score 2):

Create a wallet, and pay the merchant their Bitcoin price.

It would be much easier to clarify if you link to the merchant, so that we can actually see where you need to send it.